# Jackson Serialization: Setting field value as XML element name

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jax-rs

We are using Jackson jax-rs XML content providers for handling XML content type in our jax-rs based REST API project.
In the serializing a List of POJOs, we need to set the xml element name dynamically from a field in the POJO.

```
public class ResponsePOJO {
     @JacksonXmlProperty
     @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
     private List<Message> message = new ArrayList<Message>();
}

public class Message {
     private String type; // "Error" or "Warning"
     private String msg; // The actual message
}
```

Default Jackson serialized XML:

```
<ResponsePOJO>
    <message>
        <type>Error</type>
        <msg>Some random error message</msg>
    </message>
    <message>
        <type>Warning</type>
        <msg>Some random warning message</msg>
    </message>
</ResponsePOJO>
```

Our requirement, ie., set type as the XML element name.

```
<ResponsePOJO>
    <Error>
        <msg>Some random error message</msg>
    </Error>
    <Warning>
        <msg>Some random warning message</msg>
    </Warning>
</ResponsePOJO>
```

In order to achieve this, we wrote a custom XML serializer in the following manner:

```
public class MessageListSerializer extends
        JsonSerializer<List<Message>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(List<Message> value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        for(Message me : value){
            jgen.writeObjectField(me.getType(), me);
        }
    }
}
```

And added the serializer using annotation:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
@JsonSerialize(using=MessageListSerializer.class)
private List<Message> message = new ArrayList<Message>();
```

But while serializing the ResponsePOJO using Jackson XMLMapper, we are getting the following exception...

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Array index out of range: -2
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.XmlSerializerProvider.serializeValue(XmlSerializerProvider.java:100)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2866)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2289)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -2
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeRaw(BufferingXmlWriter.java:241)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeRaw(BaseStreamWriter.java:1113)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.writeRaw(ToXmlGenerator.java:592)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.DefaultXmlPrettyPrinter$Lf2SpacesIndenter.writeIndentation(DefaultXmlPrettyPrinter.java:517)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.DefaultXmlPrettyPrinter.writeEndObject(DefaultXmlPrettyPrinter.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.writeEndObject(ToXmlGenerator.java:422)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.XmlBeanSerializer.serialize(XmlBeanSerializer.java:119)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.XmlSerializerProvider.serializeValue(XmlSerializerProvider.java:92)
    ... 3 more
```

Could you please help me resolve this issue...

Answer (score 3):

Edit to previous solution:
You're nearly there, just need to add `@JsonIgnore` to `private String type; // "Error" or "Warning"`

```
<ResponsePOJO>
    <Error>
        <msg>error message</msg>
    </Error>
    <Warning>
        <msg>warning message</msg>
    </Warning>
</ResponsePOJO>
```

The following will output the above xml:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main demo = new Main();
        demo.run();
    }


    public void run(){

        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

        ResponsePOJO responsePOJO = new ResponsePOJO();

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setType("Error");
        message.setMsg("error message");
        Message message2 = new Message();
        message2.setType("Warning");
        message2.setMsg("warning message");

        responsePOJO.getMessage().add(message);
        responsePOJO.getMessage().add(message2);
        try {
            String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(responsePOJO);
            System.out.println(xml);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public class ResponsePOJO {
        @JacksonXmlProperty
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        @JsonSerialize(using=MessageListSerializer.class)
        private List<Message> message = new ArrayList<Message>();

        public List<Message> getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

    }


    public class Message {
        @JsonIgnore
        private String type; // "Error" or "Warning"
        private String msg; // The actual message

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getMsg() {
            return msg;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }
    }


}
```

along with the class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Pand on 08/04/2015.
 */
public class MessageListSerializer extends
        JsonSerializer<List<Main.Message>> {


    @Override
    public void serialize(List<Main.Message> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        for(Main.Message me : value){
            jgen.writeObjectField(me.getType(), me);
        }
    }


}
```

with dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Creation of multiple lists to store Error and Warning messages doesn't solve my problem. I would like to store the messages in a single list so that I can maintain the order of these messages (order is impt in my scenario). You approach would list out all the error messages first and then warning messages. Can you help me figure out who we can achieve this with Jackson using a single List.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: jgen.writeObjectField(me.getType(), me); is throwing ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception. Was able to fix in by using provider.defaultSerializeField(me.getType(), me, jgen);

Comment: With your code you'd still be getting the type tag in your XML. Did the above code, using @JsonIgnore get the result you were looking for?

Comment: yes. By using provider.defaultSerializeField(me.getType(), me, jgen); I was able to get the desired format. As you mentioned ignored the type field using @JsonIgnore annotation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got Exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value` when tried your solution with `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.2` (which transitively references to `org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4` and `com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:5.0.3`)

Comment: This does not work for Jackson 2.8+ because of [this change](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/commit/e0b105f88f9083720729dabbfdc102372d18d44b#diff-26612c39418f6410bac5cb23be5c10fd).

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem to me. I wrote a custom JsonSerializer to generate different xml element name (read from @JsonTypeName) for each item in a collection.

Here is my JsonSerializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;

public class NamedCollectionXmlSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Collection<Object>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Collection<Object> list, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        boolean toXml = gen instanceof ToXmlGenerator;
        if (!toXml) {
            // fallback to the default behavior for non-xml serialization
            gen.writeObject(list);
            return;
        }
        gen.writeStartArray();
        if (list != null) {
            for (Object item : list) {
                if (item == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                JsonTypeName jsonTypeName;
                if ((jsonTypeName = item.getClass().getAnnotation(JsonTypeName.class)) != null) {
                    // read JsonTypeName as the xml element name
                    // if JsonTypeName not present, use the default name
                    ((ToXmlGenerator) gen).setNextName(new QName("", jsonTypeName.value()));
                }
                gen.writeObject(item);
            }
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

for the following POJO (getters and constructors generated by lombok):

```
interface Message {

}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class ResponsePOJO {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JsonSerialize(using = NamedCollectionXmlSerializer.class)
    private final List<Message> messages;
}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeName("Error")
class Error implements Message {
    private final String msg;
}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeName("Warning")
class Warning implements Message {
    private final String msg;

}
```

and test code:

```
ResponsePOJO response = new ResponsePOJO(
        Arrays.asList(new Error("error1"), new Warning("warn1"), new Error("error2"))
);
new XmlMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(System.out, response);
```

this is output:

```
<ResponsePOJO>
  <Error>
    <msg>error1</msg>
  </Error>
  <Warning>
    <msg>warn1</msg>
  </Warning>
  <Error>
    <msg>error2</msg>
  </Error>
</ResponsePOJO>
```

PS: I test my code with jackson version 2.9.3

Answer (score 1):

"I cannot post it in comment since it is too long"
The following is the customized classes:

```java
 @XmlRootElement
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class MyResponse {

 @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "error", type = MyError.class),
  @XmlElement(name = "warning", type = MyWarning.class) })
 @XmlElementWrapper
  private List<MyMessage> messages = Lists.newArrayList();

  public List<MyMessage> getMessages() {
  return messages;
 }

 public void setMessages(List<MyMessage> messages) {
  this.messages = messages;
 }
}    

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyMessage {
 protected String text;

 public String getText() {
  return text;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
  this.text = text;
  }
  }

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class MyError extends MyMessage {
 }

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyWarning extends MyMessage {

}
```

I tested it with my demo code:

```java
MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
MyMessage error = new MyError();
error.setText("error");

MyMessage warning = new MyWarning();
warning.setText("warning");
myResponse.setMessages(Lists.newArrayList(error, warning));
```

and it returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myResponse> 
  <messages>
    <error>
      <text>error</text>
    </error>
    <warning>
      <text>warning</text>
    </warning>
  </messages>
</myResponse>
```

You need to tweak element name to get desired results though.

Comment: remove    @XmlElementWrapper if you don't want to see <myMessages/>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works wonderfully well with JAXB marshaller. Removed @XmlElementWrapper to suit my requirement. Do we have a Jackson equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that your approach is over complicated. I would instead restructure your message class as:

`public class Message {
     private String msg; // The actual message
}`, and subclass it based on types:

`public class Error extends Message {
}`

`public class Warning extends Message {
}`.

In addition, this approach allows you adding customized fields to each type which is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even in this case how can we set "Error" & "Warning" as XML element name, without creating separate lists for "Error" and "Warning" messages.

Comment: To be more specific, I need to maintain the order of these messages and hence use a single list List<Message> to store both Error and Warning objects. In this case, is it possible to set subclass name as XML element name.